# Git repository is showing changes commited to the files but no changes are being displayed on the webpage

Tags: git, github

I am a new bee to GitHub, currently working on Angular 9. I pushed the code to the GitHub and committed  changes were applied in the files present in repository, but is not displaying any changes on the publishing domain of the project.

Comment: The repository is not the location of the production website. What process is there to push updated code to your site?

Answer (score 0):

Did you 'push' your code to your branch? try

git push --set-upstream origin "YOUR BRANCH name" (if you are pushing to your branch the first time)

Make Sure that you are checking your branch in your git repo.

Comment: This would more appropriately be a comment on the question, not an answer, since the question doesn't seem to have enough information to properly answer.